# Using an OR statement with guards

Tags: nestjs

What I am trying to do is something functionally like this (of course, the code below is nonsense):

```
@UseGuards( AuthGuard || AdminAuthGuard )
```

I want my guards to be false only if both return false. Basically, I'd like my auth guards to be like an OR statements because the endpoint can be activated by multiple independent sources and each has its own authentication system.

Of course, I could combine those two auths in the same function. The problem is that the code would become messy as there are instance where I need to use each of them individually and I do not want an overlap with one another.

Anyone has any idea how to implement a behavior like that?

PS: Also, as additional complexity, I am using RoleGuards with one of the two login system. So RoleGuards would be applied, for example, if AdminAuth is true, but not apply is normal Auth is true.

SOLUTION: Here's how I solved this problem(I still don't know if there's a simple nestjs way of doing it. If you you, I want to know ;)).
In my original guards, I exported the validateRequest function. I created an auth guard that is called adminOrNormalAuthGuard. In there I import the functions and implement the logic I want.

As for the roleGuards, all that I'm doing is importing those validate functions. If login is normal=> return true. If special login=> result depends on guards logic.

Comment: Related github issue with *some* solutions: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/873

Answer (score 0):

As this seems related to authentication, you can follow the recomended behaviour in the doc seen here: https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#extending-guards

Basically what you can do is extend an AuthGuard composed with multiple strategies:

```
export class MyAuthGuard extends AuthGuard(['strategy_1', 'strategy_2', '...']) { ... }
```

Then you just have to set your new "MyAuthGuard" guard to your routes.

If the first strategy fail, the next one is used and so on until all strategy fails or one is successful.

Comment: The problem is that is using all these strategies as AND operator, not as OR. There is an option to one or another?

Comment: its been a while since i've used it, but reading my initial comment it should be an OR and not an AND

Answer (score 0):

> As this seems related to authentication, you can follow the recomended behaviour in the doc seen here: https://docs.nestjs.com/security/authentication#extending-guards
>
> Basically what you can do is extend an AuthGuard composed with multiple strategies:
>
> export class MyAuthGuard extends AuthGuard(['strategy_1', 'strategy_2', '...']) { ... }
> Then you just have to set your new "MyAuthGuard" guard to your routes.
>
> If the first strategy fail, the next one is used and so on until all strategy fails or one is successful.

But in the docs, the description is:

> In addition to extending the default error handling and authentication logic, we can allow authentication to go through a chain of strategies. **The first strategy to succeed, redirect, or error will halt the chain.** Authentication failures will proceed through each strategy in series, ultimately failing if all strategies fail.

Comment: You should leave a comment instead of replying to the answer provided before, it'll be better understandable this way.

Comment: exactly, follow the docs will not help you, throw a `UnauthorizedException` will halt the chain.
After reading the source code, I tried `return false` instead of throw, which works.
It turns out a strategy can have four state: succeed, redirect, error and `fail`.
succeed: return a user 
redirect: emmmmm...
error: throw
fail: return a falsy value instead of user